# Broken z-axis in splot

Tags: gnuplot

There are plenty of resources online to teach you how to draw 2d plots with broken axis, e.g. http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/. Basically what strategy used was to draw two plots using multiplot mode, and combine them together.

However, what I wished to do is to break the Z axis, consider these two surfaces:

[image: Potential Energy Surface Example]

Because of the large energy gap between two surfaces, the ground energy surface is almost "flat" in this plot, yet if we plot the ground energy surface alone, we can see it is not "flat" at all:

[image]

Is there a way of breaking the Z axis to make Gnuplot display more details of the surface? multiplot does not work here because it is a 3d plot.

Comment: Why don't you lust plot side by side? even if you succeed in breaking the z axis, the two will superpose and it will be difficult to notice the difference once they're mixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can shift the upper surface downwards and relabel the z tics manually. Take this figure as an example:

[image]

Let's work out some gnuplot magic:

```
# Make sure that there are no data points exactly at the corners
# of the xy plane (it affects the vertical borders)
set xrange [-1.001:1.001]
set yrange [-1.001:1.001]

zmin = -2
zmax = 5
dz = zmax - zmin
set zrange [zmin:zmax]

# Remove vertical borders
set border 15

# Some functions to plot
f(x,y)=x**2+y**2+10.
g(x,y)=-x**2-y**2

# Draw vertical borders by hand leaving empty space where the
# axis is broken. I have used variables zmin etc. for transparency
set for [i=-1:1:2] for [j=-1:1:2] arrow \
    from i,j,zmin-dz*0.5 to i,j,1 lw 1 nohead
set for [i=-1:1:2] for [j=-1:1:2] arrow \
    from i,j,2 to i,j,zmax lw 1 nohead

# Draw zig-zag line to denote broken axis
set for [i=-1:1:2] for [j=-1:1:2] arrow \
    from i,j,1 to i-0.05,j,1+0.25 lw 1 nohead
set for [i=-1:1:2] for [j=-1:1:2] arrow \
    from i-0.05,j,1+0.25 to i+0.05,j,1+0.75 lw 1 nohead
set for [i=-1:1:2] for [j=-1:1:2] arrow \
    from i+0.05,j,1+0.75 to i,j,2 lw 1 nohead

# Add ztics by hand. Use "for" if you have many tics
set ztics (-2, 0)
# We print the z value - 7, which is the amount we are shifting the
# upper surface
set ztics add ("10" 3, "12" 5)

# Plot shifting the surface
splot f(x,y)-7, g(x,y)
```

[image]

Note that the new borders defined with `set arrow` will be drawn behind the surface. If you want a particular one to be in the front, then take it out of the `set for` loop and add the `front` keyword to it.

Comment: Nice the zig-zag line method.