# Remove right vertical axis in gunplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to make a splot with gnuplot without the right vertical axis.
See [script.plt](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=43400879936296122428) and the respective datafile [data.dat](http://www.filedropper.com/data_13): in the script, I have 'set border 1', which means that only the bottom-left-front border of the plot should be shown (see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node162.html). However, the right-vertical border is also shown. How can I remove it?

Comment: I suspect you're mixing up the 2D and 3D behaviors. In 2D plots, use `set border 7` to achieve what you want. If you also want the tics on that axis gone, use `set ytics nomirror`.

Comment: No, the command 'set border 1' in script.plt is valid for both 2D and 3D plots, see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node162.html . In 3D plots, this command should show only the bottom-left-front border, while it shows also the right-vertical one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to do a 2D plot. The issue that you're experiencing is more complicated. Gnuplot will draw lateral borders from the bottom to the surface if you have a point drawn right at the corner whose axis you want to skip, regardless of the `set border` setting. If you want to avoid this you can play a bit with `set xrange`. Have a look at this answer (and understand what the first lines in the code are for): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833457/broken-z-axis-in-splot/35839944#35839944

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027203/remove-z-axis-in-gnuplot) which has the same issue that you are experiencing.

Comment: This solves the problem, thank you.